# How can I make an event listener fire only once?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a very simple memory matching game with 6 cards. Each card is in a `div` with the class of `.card` that contains two more `div` elements - front face of the card (just a simple green background img) and a back face of the card (a random image i've picked).

Backfaces
[image]

Frontfaces
[image]

Every card has a click event listener. Once you click the card, the card rotates from it's back side to it's front side and reveals the image. If the two images you've picked are a match, you receive +1 **Score**. If the images you've picked do not happen to be a match, all of the cards rotate to their back face and you receive +1 to "**Fails**" and you lose the game.

The main problem is that I can click and rotate the **same** card over and over again due to the event listener. Is there any way to make it fire only once? I've tried to use `once: true` on the event listener but that caused the cards to be unclickable even after losing the game thus i've removed it.

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
const images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
let scoreElement = document.getElementById("score");
let failsElement = document.getElementById("fails");
let failsAmount = 0;
let scoreAmount = 0;
let pickedCards = [];

function pickCards() {
    // Iterate through every div with the class of ".card"
    for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        // Add an event listener to them
        cards[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            // Rotate the card
            cards[i].classList.toggle("flipcard");
            // After clicking on the card that contains the img, push the img into the pickedCards array.
            pickedCards.push(images[i]);
            checkForMatch();
        });
    }
}

function checkForMatch() {
    // Check the source of the images from the array
    if (pickedCards[0].src == pickedCards[1].src) {
        alert("Match! +1 score");
        scoreAmount++;
        scoreElement.textContent = "Score: " + scoreAmount;
        // Empty the array so the player can pick another 2 cards
        pickedCards = [];
    }

    else {
        hideCards();
        alert("Not a match! Sorry!");
        failsAmount++;
        failsElement.textContent = "Fails: " + failsAmount;
        pickedCards = [];
    }
}

function hideCards() {
    for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Remove the flipcard class from the cards and show the front face again.
            cards[i].classList.remove("flipcard");
        }, 1000); 
    }
}

pickCards();
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,body {
    height: 100%;
}

.card-container {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    perspective: 1200;
}

.flipcard {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transition: all 0.7s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    margin: 0em 1em;
}

.front-card, .back-card {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front-card {
    background: url("./IMGs/block.jpg") no-repeat center/cover;
}

.back-card {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.back-card img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

#score, #fails {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="front-card"></div>
            <div id="card1" class="back-card"><img src="IMGs/eric.jpg" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="front-card"></div>
            <div id="card2" class="back-card"><img src="IMGs/john.webp" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="front-card"></div>
            <div id="card3" class="back-card"><img src="IMGs/salim.png" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="front-card"></div>
            <div id="card4" class="back-card"><img src="IMGs/salim.png" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="front-card"></div>
            <div id="card5" class="back-card"><img src="IMGs/eric.jpg" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="front-card"></div>
            <div id="card6" class="back-card"><img src="IMGs/john.webp" alt=""></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p id="score">Score: 0</p>
    <p id="fails">Fails: 0</p>
```

I am still new to this, so any tips will be aprecitated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case just add an if-statement before flipping and checking for match:

```
cards[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
  if (!cards[i].classList.contains('flipcard')) {
     cards[i].classList.toggle('flipcard')
     pickedCards.push(images[i])
     checkForMatch()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you delegate you can test much better than turning off event handlers

```
document.querySelector(".card-container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("div");
  if (tgt && tgt.classList.contains("card")) {
    if (tgt.classList.contains("clicked")) return;
    tgt.classList.add("clicked");
    .... // rest of handling here
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to solve.

1. Create an Array or variables to check if the respective card was clicked. Example:

   cardsClicked = [false, false, false, false, false, false];
2. On the click event, modify the selected cardsClicked[n] to true. AND, check (IF) the selected card already was selected.

That's it.